# Visual Studio Code shows incorrect error squiggle for the pipe (|) operator (c++20)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20

Visual Studio Code marks red the pipe operator (`|`) as well as other functions taken from the `ranges` library and shows an error squiggle even though the code compiles fine using `g++-12 -std=c++20 main.cpp`. Is it a missing feature/bug in the C/C++ extension or are my error squiggles not aligned well with my actual compiler?

```
// main.cpp
#include <optional>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
  auto vv = v | std::views::filter([](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
  return 0;
}
```

Error popup when I go over `|` in C++ code in Visual Studio Code:

```
no operator "|" matches these operandsC/C++(349)
main.cpp(11, 15): operand types are: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> | std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Filter, lambda [](int x)->bool>
```

My full setup:

- Visual Studio Code 1.74.2
- [C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack)
- `CMake` v3.22.1
- `g++` v12.1.0
- `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > `Cpp Standard` > `c++20`
- `C/C++: Change Configuration Provider` -> `CMake Tools` (I assume this makes error squiggles be generated by CMake used during compilation when I hit F7)

To fix this I tried with no success:

- setting `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > `Cpp Standard` to `c++23` and back to `c++20` back again (both standards support `ranges` the way I use them)
- tried making sure I am using the same compiler for error squiggles and for compilation using CMake
- setting `C_Cpp.default.compilerPath` to `/usr/bin/g++-12` and `/usr/bin/g++-11` in settings.json (I have both installed and the both support the `|` operator as well as `ranges`)

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), like your errors. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions. And for errors, please make sure you copy-paste the full and complete build log.

Comment: IMHO, this is one case where you should not use `auto` and code it using older techniques, such as single step initializations and multiple variables.

Comment: C++20 standard should be set in your `CMakeLists.txt`, not in IDE preferences. Also, if the code actually compiles and runs, it may very well be possible that IntelliSense doesn't understand that syntax yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I observed is an open issue with the latest versions of the `C/C++` extension in vscode which can be tracked here:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10252.

The current walkaround is to downgrade the `C/C++` extension in Visual Studio Code to v1.12.4 which was the latest version giving correct type hints for `ranges` library:

- go to the *Extensions* tab in your vscode
- select `C/C++`
- hit `Uninstall`
- hit `Install Another version` and select `1.12.4`.

Comment: the issue can now be observed with current pre-release version 1.19.1 (the same with release version 1.18.5). any idea why? did the bug re-appear?

Comment: I haven't used that feature in a long time so I don't know. I'd recommend asking at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/.

Comment: Im wondering if this is the issue I am having with the Keypad library for Arduino. 

const byte ROW_PINS[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
const byte COL_PINS[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
const char BUTTONS[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1', '2', '3', 'A'}, // Row 0
    {'4', '5', '6', 'B'}, // Row 1
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'}, // Row 2
    {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}  // Row 3
};

no instance of constructor "Keypad::Keypad" matches the argument listC/C++(289)
keypad-control.ino(114, 21): argument types are: (char *, const byte [4], const byte [4], const byte, const byte)

Yet it compiles and runs perfectly.